# Can't filter Pandas Series of lists by length

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a Series of ratings, each contained in a list:
ratings_series = pd.Series([[5.7],[],[6.3],...])

I want to only include the ratings with values i.e disclude empty strings. I've tried loads of ways to filter the Series, the main one being

`film_filtered2 = ratings_series[len(ratings_series) > 0]`
I also tried

```
film_filtered2 = ratings_series.loc[lambda x : (len(x) > 0)]
```

and it results in **KeyError: 'True: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'**

I've copied code verbatim from other sources on how to 'filter a series by a condition' but whenever I substitute my data structures in, it's incorrect. I assume the solution is very basic, I just don't know why this specific instance isn't working. There's a lot of data but I'm almost certain the only variations of data are lists of 1 or 0

Comment: You don't state what your intended goal is. You also don't give an example dataset, the corresponding example output (or error), and what you actually expect as output. Those are helpful for people to help solve your problem.

Comment: @9769953 I thought so but then I thought that as it's a series, it does element-wise operations when the series is referenced in the series[]. I'm not sure. I edited and showed another attempt I tried, directly from a webpage

Comment: `ratings_series = [5.7],[],[6.3],...`: do you mean `ratings_series = pd.Series([[5.7],[],[6.3],...])` instead?

Comment: @9769953 Yeah, that's what I meant. And I specified initially what I'm intending - to filter the series by only lists with contents in it. I showed another example above with the error if that helps

Comment: @9769953 It is a series, I just didn't type it out here

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can probably use `.apply` on the series, with `len` as the function to apply. This then works per element:

```
>>> ratings_series = pd.Series([[5.7],[],[6.3]])
>>> ratings_series
0    [5.7]
1       []
2    [6.3]
dtype: object
>>> ratings_series.apply(len)
0    1
1    0
2    1
dtype: int64
>>> ratings_series[ratings_series.apply(len) > 0]
0    [5.7]
2    [6.3]
dtype: object
```

As a side note, I do have a feeling that a series is the wrong data type (basically, a list of lists), but I can't suggest a better datatype right now (also dependent on other context).

Comment: This Error comes up: TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len(). Is this implying there are other values in the series other than lists? I'm reading for an API so I have no control over the data stuctures unfortunately

Comment: @ChrisThomas Yes, then next to lists, there are also (single) floats in the series. The question is then: do you want to convert these into a 1-element list, remove them entirely, or keep them as they are?